# Delete registration after 24 hours if not confirmed (Rails, Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is there a way, maybe implemented and not seen by me, or somehow for gem 'Devise', to remove registrations of users that haven't confirmed their account for 24 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create your own async task and use [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) to plan it every minute to scope your users with something like

```rb
User.where(confirmed_at: nil).where('created_at < ?', 1.day.ago).destroy_all
```

Comment: Wonderful, thank you my dear friend